# DSC - alter MOF after compiling it

Tags: powershell, dsc

Is it possible to alter a MOF file in DSC after compiling it? I'm trying to have a generic MOF in a pull server and from a client ask for that MOF with specific parameters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The MOF is just a text file; you could modify it yourself.

But there's no provision in the pull server that would take a parameter and modify the requested MOF on the fly. Additionally you'd have to recalculate the checksum if you did modify it.

What exactly are you trying to do that this would be necessary?

Comment: I'm trying to configure N number of clients without having the same amount of MOFs in the Pull Server. The MOF that is applied in the client should have data related to that client.

Comment: @MNFourçans that's not the way DSC is intended to work. Either the N clients can all use an identical configuration (in which case give them all the same GUID and they'll all get the same config), or you should be generating the various configs programmatically at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The Guid is used to identify the nodes. If you share the Guid across multiple nodes then it is difficult to identify which node hasn't gotten an update (using the status end point). The correct way of doing it is to use configuration data and compile for the individual nodes. Here is a link to the blog on how to do the same https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2014/01/09/separating-what-from-where-in-powershell-dsc/